# Dividing a Pandas dataframe into smaller chunks based of the sum of one column

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a large Pandas dataframe that is structured like this:

```
  x     y   count
blah  blah    4
blah  blah    12
blah  blah    15
...
```

The final sum of the count column is around 48,000. I want to split the overall dataframe into around twelve different chunks. The condition for this split is that I want the count of the column in that chunk to be around 4,000. So the length of each chunk can be different but the sum of the count column must be around 4,000.

Is there a quick efficient way of accomplishing this? My current attempt involves iterating through the dataframe and appending until the sum of rows exceeds 4,000 but it is quite slow:

```
df_sum = 4000

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','count'])

i = 1

for index, row in df.iterrows():

     appended_sum = 0

     if appended_sum < df_sum:

        appended_sum += row['count']

        a_df.loc[len(a_df)] = row

    else:

        a_df.to_csv('split_'+str(i)+'.csv', index=False)

        i+=1

        a_df= a_df.iloc[0:0]
        appended_sum = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with this as a limited example:

```
      x     y  count
0  blah  blah      4
1  blah  blah     12
2  blah  blah     15
0  blah  blah      4
1  blah  blah     12
2  blah  blah     15
0  blah  blah      4
1  blah  blah     12
2  blah  blah     15
```

This could work:

```
df_sum = 30
df['total'] = df['count'].cumsum()
df['batch'] = (df['total'] / df_sum).astype(int)
grouped = df.groupby('batch')
for group in grouped.groups.keys():
    data = grouped.get_group(group)
    # do something with the data
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks.