# Pandas - partition a dataframe into two groups with an approximate mean value

Tags: python, pandas, partitioning

I want to split all rows into two groups that have similar means.

I have a dataframe of about 50 rows but this could go into several thousands with a column of interest called 'value'.

```
             value  total   bucket
300048137   3.0741  3.0741  0
352969997   2.1024  5.1765  0
abc13.com   4.5237  9.7002  0
abc7.com    5.8202  15.5204 0
abcnews.go.com  6.7270  22.2474 0
........
www.legacy.com  12.6609 263.0797    1
www.math-aids.com   10.9832 274.0629    1
```

So far I tried using cumulative sum for which total column was created then I essentially made the split based on where the mid-point of the total column is. Based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763362/dividing-a-pandas-dataframe-into-smaller-chunks-based-of-the-sum-of-one-column).

```
test['total'] = test['value'].cumsum()
df_sum = test['value'].sum()//2 
test['bucket'] = np.where(test['total'] <= df_sum, 0,1)
```

If I try to group them and take the average for each group then the difference is quite significant

```
display(test.groupby('bucket')['value'].mean())

bucket
0     7.456262
1    10.773905
```

Is there a way I could achieve this partition based on means instead of sums? I was thinking about using expanding means from pandas but couldn't find a proper way to do it.

Comment: could you add a few more lines as example data with the desired output for it please?

Comment: Sure, I added some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but possibly you want to groupy by quantiles of a column. If so:

```py
test['bucket'] = pd.qcut(test['value'], q=2, labels=False)
```

which will have bucket=0 for the half of rows with the lesser `value` values. And 1 for the rest. By tweakign the `q` parameter you can have as many groups as you want (as long as <= number of rows).

Edit:
New attemp, now that I think I understand better your aim:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame( {'value':pd.np.arange(100)})

df['group'] = df['value'].argsort().mod(2)
df.groupby('group')['value'].mean()
# group
# 0    49
# 1    50
# Name: value, dtype: int64
​
df['group'] = df['value'].argsort().mod(3)
df.groupby('group')['value'].mean()
#group
# 0    49.5
# 1    49.0
# 2    50.0
# Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi! I added a few more details to the post. I want to create two groups in such a way that the mean value of group A is not too different from group B. I'll try your approach looks promising.

Comment: The difference between group 0 and group 1 average value is too great if I were to use this approach. e.g 0   = 4.784672; 1  =  12.914672

Comment: okay, I understand better what you want. And yeah my code is not cattering for that, I think you want something closer to a bin packing alogrithm (in the advanced version at least). I may update with something more relevant later.

Comment: Indeed. For this case the number of items in each bin doesn't matter that much as long as the two groups have similar averages.

Comment: Check my update

Comment: That was quick. Honestly, I wasn't expecting that a simple solution would give such a good approximation. It works as expected.

Comment: Glad it helps, indeed a simple trick.

Comment: do you happen to know of a more advanced solution where the approximation would be closer? For example, I'd like to have an even closer means for now they are about 0 =   8.721, 1 =   8.977. For a case where I have about 100 rows I ended up having the means at: 0   =  8.720 1 =   10.675.